# count number of sequence matches using two rows in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence

```
       Tijd nummer schaap                     code   Modifier comment status
1     2.971             1                stilstaan       <NA>      NA  START
2     5.457             1                   ruiken aan object      NA  POINT
3    10.703             1                stilstaan       <NA>      NA   STOP
4    10.704             1                    lopen       <NA>      NA  START
5    12.959             1                    lopen       <NA>      NA   STOP
6    12.960             1                stilstaan       <NA>      NA  START
7    22.732             1                   ruiken aan object      NA  POINT
8    29.383             1                stilstaan       <NA>      NA   STOP
9    29.384             1                    lopen       <NA>      NA  START
10   42.568             1                    lopen       <NA>      NA   STOP
11   42.569             1                   ruiken aan object      NA  POINT
12   49.206             1                    lopen       <NA>      NA  START
13   66.533             1                    lopen       <NA>      NA   STOP
14   66.534             1                stilstaan       <NA>      NA  START
15   67.134             1                   ruiken aan object      NA  POINT
16   72.999             1                stilstaan       <NA>      NA   STOP
17   73.000             1                    lopen       <NA>      NA  START
18   77.480             1                    lopen       <NA>      NA   STOP
19   77.481             1                stilstaan       <NA>      NA  START
20   81.773             1               rondkijken       <NA>      NA  START
```

I'm a behavioral biology student doing an internship and I have always used R to do my statistics but I sincerely don't know how to do what I want right now. This dataframe contains my observations (in dutch) and I want to count how many times "stilstaan" is followed by "ruiken" with modifier "aan object". I've been unable to find a way to do exactly what I want. I am able to count the number of times "stilstaan" is followed by "ruiken" using the code below but I don't know how to include the modifier. Is there a way to do this or am I asking for the impossible?

```
S=Excel_bestand_schapen
seq=c("stilstaan", "ruiken")
library(zoo)
result=rollapply(S, 2, identical, seq)
length(result[result == TRUE])
```

Comment: Does `ruiken` always follow `stilstaan`, and does `ruiken` always have a modifier `aan object`?

Comment: Can you post the result of `dput(head(df, 10))` instead so that it'll be easier to copy your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the following code to filter for the rows that meet the requirement. `lead` can move the entire vector forward. The answer of this dataset is three.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  filter(code %in% "stilstaan" & lead(code) %in% "ruiken" & lead(Modifier) %in% "aan object") 

nrow(dat2)
# [1] 3
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "       Tijd 'nummer schaap'                     code   Modifier comment status
1     2.971             1                stilstaan       NA      NA  START
                  2     5.457             1                   ruiken 'aan object'      NA  POINT
                  3    10.703             1                stilstaan         NA      NA   STOP
                  4    10.704             1                    lopen         NA      NA  START
                  5    12.959             1                    lopen         NA      NA   STOP
                  6    12.960             1                stilstaan         NA      NA  START
                  7    22.732             1                   ruiken 'aan object'      NA  POINT
                  8    29.383             1                stilstaan         NA      NA   STOP
                  9    29.384             1                    lopen         NA      NA  START
                  10   42.568             1                    lopen         NA      NA   STOP
                  11   42.569             1                   ruiken 'aan object'      NA  POINT
                  12   49.206             1                    lopen         NA      NA  START
                  13   66.533             1                    lopen         NA      NA   STOP
                  14   66.534             1                stilstaan         NA      NA  START
                  15   67.134             1                   ruiken 'aan object'      NA  POINT
                  16   72.999             1                stilstaan         NA      NA   STOP
                  17   73.000             1                    lopen         NA      NA  START
                  18   77.480             1                    lopen         NA      NA   STOP
                  19   77.481             1                stilstaan         NA      NA  START
                  20   81.773             1               rondkijken         NA      NA  START",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly! And I can even use 2 modifiers if I need to in the future, this code is also very useful other future projects

Answer (score 0):

Using base R and www's dat-data-frame:

```
sum(ifelse((dat$code == "stilstaan") & 
             (c(dat$code[2:length(dat$code)], NA) == "ruiken") &
             (c(dat$Modifier[2:length(dat$Modifier)], NA) == "aan object"),
           1, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can collapse the relevant columns into a single string

```
collapse <- paste(paste(dat$code, dat$Modifier), collapse=" ")
# [1] "stilstaan NA ruiken aan object stilstaan NA lopen ...
```

And define the pattern you want to search for

```
pattern <- "stilstaan NA ruiken aan object"
```

Use `stringr::str_count` to count matches

```
stringr::str_count(pattern, collapse)
# 3
```